# From Python dataframe to nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use an api and would need to put my dataframe  in a dictionary format first.
The dataframe df that looks like this:

```
    OrigC  OrigZ  OrigN Weigh  DestC   DestZ    DestN
0      PL     97    TP    59     DE      63       SN
```

**Exepected output of the first row:**

```
{"section":[
    {"location":
        {
        "zipCode":
            {"OrigC": "PL",
            "OrigZ":"97"},
        "location": {"id": "1"},
        "OrigN": "TP"
            },
    "carriageParameter":
        {"road":
            {"truckLoad": "Auto"}
        },
    "load":
        {"Weigh": "59",
        "unit": "ton",
        "showEmissionsAtResponse": "true"
        }
    },
    {"location":
        {
        "zipCode":
            {"DestC": "DE",
            "DestZ":"63"},
        "location": {"id": "2"},
        "DestN": "SN"
            },
    "carriageParameter":
        {"road":
            {"truckLoad":"Auto"}
        },
    "unload":
        {"WEIGHTTONS":"59",
        "unit": "ton",
        "showEmissionsAtResponse": "true"
        }
    }]}
```

Note that there is static information in the dictionary that doesn't require any change.

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iterrows.

```
dic = {}
dic['section'] = []
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    
    in_dict = {
        'location': {
            'zip_code': {
                'OrigC': row['OrigC'],
                'OrigZ': row['OrigZ'],
                },
            'location': {'id': ix+1}, # I am guessing here.
            'OrigN': 'TP',  
        },
        'CarriageParameter': {
            'road': {
                'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },
        'load': {
            'Weigh': str(row['Weigh']),
        } 
        }
    
    
    dic['section'].append(in_dict)
```

Note that this is not the entire entry, but I think it is clear enough to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks @warped, i tried the code, executed but nothing is printed on the ouput, there is no errors showed

Comment: What would you like to print?

Comment: the dictionary structure as described in the expected output

Comment: try `print(dic)`  ?

Comment: for prettier prints you can check out [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html). In your case: `import pprint` and then `pprint.pprint(dic)`

Comment: seems lile it keep appending previous rows from the dataframe.
how can i fix that ?

Comment: @GomelsarBARO I don't understand what you mean. could you edit your question with the current and the desired output?